# Terminal is prompting me for a password but says authentication failed after I give my CORRECT password

Tags: drivers, wireless, adapter

I'm attempting to install a USB wifi adapter driver which is not included in Ubuntu. I don't have access to direct ethernet connection. I have an EDUP usb wifi adapter (Realtek) that has drivers for Linux, all I want to do is install the driver. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. The file name is "install.sh" I drag and dropped the file into terminal and it then prompted me for a password. I gave my perfectly correct sudo password yet it still says authentication failed. I must be doing something wrong, can anyone help? I am a pretty new user of Ubuntu.

Comment: Try running the `install.sh` script directly from the terminal with `sudo ./install.sh` and see if it does the job. You can also run `sudo su` to enter into super user and simply run `./install.sh`, you won't be prompted for the password as you are already on an elevated privileges user environment. Please inform if you succeed or what results you receive, simply edit your question and add the details as needed. Regards

Comment: Ok so when I ran sudo ./install.sh it prompted me for my sudo password which I typed in correctly. Then I got "sudo: ./install.sh: command not found" the .sh file that im trying to install is in /home/kevin/downloads. When i ran sudo su i got "bash: ./install.sh: no such file or directory. When I try to navigate there with terminal it says no such file or directory. I'm clearly missing something here 

Comment: I was able to start running the .sh file. However, it came back with "compile make driver error: 127"

Comment: Please add the complete output

Comment: The directory should be `/home/kevin/Downloads`, missing the uppercase in "Downloads" makes a difference. Please just change to that directory from a terminal and try again. Use: `cd /home/kevin/Downloads` and enter the folder where `install.sh` resides. If it is inside "Downloads", just try again with `sudo install.sh` and let us know about the results by editing your answer and add the complete output as @MaxSilvester suggests. Regards.

Comment: For what is about the `compile make driver error: 127`, sounds like something that the script's provider should help you with. So, your first line of investigation should be consulting with'em.

Comment: This wirelss adapter is a piece of crap anyway im just going to buy one that works with Ubuntu. Thank-you for all your help. I have learned some things.